# Date(y-m-d) конвентировать в time() !?

Tags: дата, timestamp, php, время

Привет ребята, мне нужно сделать `date("d-m-Y")` конверт в `time()`...
Может кто-то сталкивался подобной задачей...Заранее спасибо
Например:
    $date = "24/03/2014";
    // $date конвентировать unix time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так не пробовали?

```
$time = strtotime('26/03/2014');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670797/convert-date-to-unixtime-php

спасибо...нашел здесь